# How do you write a JUnit test for an empty function Pointcut

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to write a JUnit test for this method. I am not familiar with Pointcut. Any advice?

```
 /**
     * Pointcut that matches all repositories, services and Web REST endpoints.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)" +
        " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)" +
        " || within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void springBeanPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new test and have it call springBeanPointcut()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@SpringBootTest
class LoggingTest {

    @Autowired
    private Logging log;
    
    @Test
    void springBeanPointcutTest(){
        log.springBeanPointcut();
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```